# How can we connect and execute oracle database objects from Sybase database objects

Tags: oracle, sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere, sybaseiq, sybase-ase-15.7

Could you please anybody let me know how to connect to oracle database and execute the stored procedure/function from Sybase database objects?

Comment: You can call Sybase stored procs & access Sybase data from Oracle by using the Oracle Database Gateway for Sybase. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/gateways.112/e12067.pdf - is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the Oracle Gateway for ODBC as an option.  It is free (the other database-specific gateways can be costly) and fairly easy to setup.  Check the Oracle docs for further information.

Simply put, with this approach you'll create a Oracle dblink that will be resolved by a listener that will in turn call the gateway which will communicate with the Sybase database via ODBC.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

you have tagged your question with sybase-sql-anywhere, sybaseiq, sybase-ase-15.7 - these are separate SAP (ex Sybase) products - each has its own methods of connecting to remote databases.

If you mean SQL Anywhere and you want to execute Oracle procedures **from** SQL Anywhere (not the other way round) then the basic steps are

a) define a remote server in the SQLA database for the Oracle
    database ( [CREATE SERVER](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbusage/creating-remote-servers-using-sql.html*d5e40186), [CREATE EXTERNAL LOGIN](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbusage/external-login-omni-using.html*d5e40960))

b) define a remote procedure in the SQLA database for the Oracle
    procedure ([CREATE PROCEDURE ... AT ...](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#sa160/en/dbreference/create-procedure-user-defined-statement.html))

I have linked the SQL commands above, to the SAP online documentation. If you have problems I suggest asking at the dedicated SQL Anywhere support forum http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/